# matplotlib legend location is uncomprehending

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I try to place the legend on the plot, but matplotlib place at the location in a uncomprehending way.Can any one tell me the reason?

> **The image content show details.**
>
> [image]

Comment: Can you make your question more specific? There is a really good guide provided by the matplotlib website: [Legend guide](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html)

Comment: @TheIdealis The black word location on the picture i think it should be red word location.  matplotlib use "lower right" way but i think it should be "upper left" base on center point `(x, y)`. I can't understand matplotlib's way.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is intended. In the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html) it says that you can use `loc` and `bbox_to_anchor` together. In this case, `loc` specifies which corner of the legend is located at `bbox_to_anchor`:

> A 2-tuple (x, y) places the corner of the legend specified by loc at x, y. For example, to put the legend's upper right-hand corner in the center of the axes (or figure) the following keywords can be used:

```py
    loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 0.5)
```

However, if you only use `loc` the legend is placed in the way you thought it should be placed.

Comment: When use `loc=(x,y)` and `bbox_to_anchor` parameter together, i still couldn't understand matplotlib's way.

Comment: If you use `loc=(x,y)` and `bbox_to_anchor` the lower left corner of the legend will be placed at `loc` and `bbox_to_anchor` will be ignored.